# On a problem assuming Diffie-Hellman oracle

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm

If we have a Diffie-Hellman oracle then given $g^x$ and $g^y$ we can construct $g^{xy}$.

Can we construct $g^{x^{-1}}$ given $g^x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the group is of known prime order $q$ (which is usually the setting in which DH is considered), then $g^{1/x} = g^{x^{q-2}}$, and the latter can be obtained with $O(\log q)$ calls to the DH oracle.

Comment: I thought the order is 2q.

Comment: That's not a standard setting (for example DDH is trivially broken in a group of order $2q$; moreover, note that $x^{-1}$ isn't even well defined for half of the possible values of $x$), but the same approach is straightforward to extend to that case as well.

Comment: Thank you. I am curious about your comment ddh is broken trivially on a group of order 2q. Why?

Comment: Because it's easy to recognize the subgroup of order q (which contains half of the elements) and in a DDH triple $(g^x, g^y, g^z)$, the last element being in the subgroup is clearly not independent of the other two being in the subgroup.